# Should I spend my Mythril on Relics as soon as it reaches 50?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

I know Mythril can be used to heal a party and restore Stamina but it really seems to shine as a Relic Draw item. Should I pretty much never have more than 50 Mythril? Or is it something that should be saved for the REALLY good stuff that comes around? I have not been playing long so I have only seen an event that halved the price of an 11x draw to 25, nothing yet that required MORE than 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the x11 draws to be the best thing to spend your Mythril on, personally.  It's a slight discount over individual draws.  However, you definitely shouldn't spend them as soon as you hit 50 - it's usually best to wait until there's a Relic Draw event with a 5-star item you WANT in it.  The boosted drop rates for certain 5-stars during those events make it at least somewhat likely you can get it, and if not you'll get something related, since the events are usually themed.

For example, one of the current events has boosted drop rates for Vincent's and other FFVII side characters' Unique Soul Break equipment.  If you plan to use those characters, you should spend your Mythril now - but if not, save it up and be able to take multiple draws when an item for a character you do use comes up.